# What's Ext.apply xtype means?

Tags: extjs

I one project I see :

```
 initComponent: function() {

        var me = this;

        Ext.apply(me, {
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'stockform'
                }
            ]
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
```

What's this means? Tell me please. 
  I know Ext.apply() is used to simplify the copying of many properties from a source to a target object

```
var x = {a: 1, c:3, e:5};
Ext.apply(x, {b:2, d:4, f:6});

console.log(x); // Object {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5, f: 6}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It for applying given properties for given object. 
In your case your componentn will be extending with property `items` which has internal component with type `stockform`. `xtype` is type shortcat.

Somwthere in ExtJs library OR in your project exists component with defined xtype `stockform`. Defining xtype `stockform` for component goes via adding property `alias: "widget.stockform"`.

Answer (score 2):

These are two questions in one, in fact:

1. What `Ext.apply` does?
2. What is an `xtype`?

Re 1: [Ext.apply](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext-method-apply) takes (usually) 2 objects as arguments: `target` and `source` and it copies all properties from the source object to the target object.

Re 2: `xtype` is a short name for a component (class), an alias. See "[What is an xtype ... and other types](http://extjs.eu/what-is-an-xtype/)" article for a detailed explanation.